# Change element color based on background, that its on

Tags: html, jquery, css

I would like to change an elements color based on the background, that it is standing on (not the background-color of the element itself).

In this example the logo is changing color based on the background: https://www.richardekwonye.com/

I can't seem to find anything on how that is done.

Thanks!

Comment: You could try either mix-blend-mode or filter (https://css-tricks.com/methods-contrasting-text-backgrounds/)

Comment: Rad! Thanks, I'll try that - will post the code here, if I can work something out.

Comment: It is on the Header_header_xxx tag, `mix-blend-mode: difference`

Comment: Hi @Adam --- I wrote an article a while back about why this can be a generally bad design concept, with examples: [Busy Background Breaks Bulletin](https://tangledweb.xyz/busy-background-breaks-bulletin-f4ff4bf67e5a) okay or purely decorative, but it can significantly interfere with readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the commenters said, it's done through `mix-blend-mode` CSS property. [Official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode).

Here's a proof-of-concept:

```css
div.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: green;
}

h1.header {
  display: inline-block;
  color: darkgray;
}

h1.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  color: lightgray;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <h1 class="header">Welcome to StackOverflow!</h1>
  <h1 class="logo">Hello</h1>
</div>
```